# Interface Builder for Dummies: How to set an action to an UIBarButtonItem in Xcode 4?

Tags: xcode, interface-builder

I am trying to set the action for a UIBarButtonItem I have in my MainWindow.xib. I keep going round and round and I'm not getting anywhere. My controller hierarchy is as follows:

```
UITabBarController
    UITabBar
    UINavigationController
        UINavigationBar
        UIViewController
            UINavigationItem
                UIBarButtonItem // THIS
        UITabBarItem
```

How can I set the action to it? I see a "selector" option in IB, but I'm not sure how to set it.

Comment: Are you trying to set the action with IB or programmatically?

Comment: I've been trying programmatically because I can't figure out IB... I don't really care ultimately which way it goes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, based on your comment answer, you'll have to use the `target`and `action` properties.

Target is the object that will receive the action.
Action is a selector (a method), from the target object.

```
myBarButtonItem.target = self;
myBarButtonItem.action = @selector( myMethod: );
```

Remember action method must have the following signature:

```
- ( IBAction )myMethod: ( id )sender;
```

The sender object will be the object that triggered the action, in your case the UIBarButtonItem.

Comment: Nice, it worked! I think I was close with my attempts, except I never set the `target` property and I had my method as `(void)` instead of `(IBAction)` and that would probably be why I wasn't getting anywhere... Just out of curiosity, in Xcode 4, is there a way to do the same through IB (trying to get a full understanding...)?

Comment: Well, actually, IBAction is defined as void... But it let knows IB that it can be used as an action.

Comment: From IB, just press the command key from your button, and drag to your class object... you will see a line, then the name of the possible actions when you're on the object.